How handle null in dynamic pivot query
I am writing a SQL query for create a sheet for attendance of employees, I am using pivot for that which looks like this
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[demoforattendance]      
(      
    @year varchar(max),      
    @month varchar(max),      
    @firstname varchar(max) = null        
)      
AS      
BEGIN      
    DECLARE @currentmonthy varchar(max);      
    DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max);      
      
    DECLARE @stdate date = @year + '-' + @month + '-' + '01';      
    DECLARE @eddate date = (SELECT EOMONTH(@stdate, 0));      
      
    WITH dates_CTE (date) AS (      
        SELECT @stdate       
        UNION ALL      
        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, date)      
        FROM dates_CTE      
        WHERE date < @eddate      
    )      
          
    SELECT @currentmonthy = COALESCE(@currentmonthy + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(Date) FROM (SELECT date FROM dates_CTE) a      
      
    SELECT @Query =       
    'SELECT id, firstname, lastname, ' + isnull(@currentmonthy,'A') + '       
    FROM      
    (      
        SELECT ED.id, date,      
       ''p'' AS totalHrs,      
        firstname, lastname       
        FROM Employee.EmployeeDetail ED      
        LEFT JOIN Employee.EmployeeActivityDetail EA ON ED.id = EA.id                                                                                                                                                                                          
  
    
             
        WHERE (@firstname IS NULL OR firstname = @firstname)      
        GROUP BY firstname, lastname, date, ED.id      
    ) t1       
    PIVOT (      
        MAX(totalHrs) FOR date IN (' + @currentmonthy + ')      
    ) t2';      
      
    PRINT @Query;      
          
    -- Execute the dynamic query with parameterization      
    EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@firstname varchar(max)', @firstname;       
END  

This is still a incomplete query but my question here is how can I handle null values which I am getting in @currentmonthy column
Does anyone have any idea regarding that?
I am trying to write a SQL query for attendance using pivot for a specific month and year

But i need all the dates
